# Lex and Yacc issue with comments

Tags: lex

I am trying to locate the root cause of an issue. I have the following line that needs to be parsed -

```
sample format "string";
```

Where `sample` and `format` need to be tokenized and whatever is in the inverted commas needs to be provided to the Parser file.
There is a catch however, if I have a perl style comment `#` inside the string, then I get an error.

In the `lexer.l`, I have the following -

```
stringIdentifier [^"]+

<STRING_S>{stringIdentifier} {
    strncpy(yylval.str, yytext,1023);
    yylval.str[1023] = '\0';
  return IDENTIFIER;
}

<*>"//".*  {
}

<*>"#".* {
} 

<INITIAL>{s}{a}{m}{p}{l}{e} {
    BEGIN(SAMPLE_S);
    return SAMPLE;
}

<SAMPLE_S>{f}{o}{r}{m}{a}{t} {
    return FORMAT;
}
<SAMPLE_S>"\"" {
    BEGIN(STRING_S);
    return INVERTED_COMMA;
}

<STRING_S>"\"" {
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
    return INVERTED_COMMA;
}
```

In the `Parser.y` I have the following rule:

```
pass : SAMPLE FORMAT INVERTED_COMMA IDENTIFIER INVERTED_COMMA 
{

};
```

However, when I give `sample format "abc;"`  it works, however, when I add a comment character `#` in the string it fails. Could you please help with this

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the way you have used the **default** *start conditions*. A quick read of the [lex/flex manual explains their operation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html).

The `<*>` means that the following pattern is applied in every state. This includes inside a string, which is indicated by the `S_STRING` state. To stop the comment pattern operating inside the string you need to *exclude* the `S_STRING` state from `<*>`. You can do this by listing all the other applicable states, which enumerate, in your example, to `<INITIAL,S_SAMPLE>`. The comment rules then become:

```
<INITIAL,SAMPLE_S>"//".* {
}

<INITIAL,SAMPLE_S>"#".* {
}
```

And that's it. It now works! (I have tested it BTW)